# java.net.SocketException: Обрыв канала (Write failed)

Tags: java, сокет, потоки-данных, io

Добрый день, товарищи.
Делаю штуку для обмена файлами с сервером и при записи с клиента приходит такая ошибка:

```
java.net.SocketException: Обрыв канала (Write failed)
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:111)
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:155)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$BlockDataOutputStream.drain(ObjectOutputStream.java:1877)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$BlockDataOutputStream.setBlockDataMode(ObjectOutputStream.java:1786)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeFatalException(ObjectOutputStream.java:1580)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:351)
at models.CloudCore.putFile(CloudCore.java:32)
at ClientFrame$1.actionPerformed(ClientFrame.java:62)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6533)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:90)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
Suppressed: java.net.SocketException: Обрыв канала (Write failed)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:111)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:155)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$BlockDataOutputStream.drain(ObjectOutputStream.java:1877)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$BlockDataOutputStream.flush(ObjectOutputStream.java:1822)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.flush(ObjectOutputStream.java:719)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.close(ObjectOutputStream.java:740)
    at models.CloudCore.putFile(CloudCore.java:34)
    ... 37 more
```

Сам код клиента:

```
public class CloudCore {
public List<File> localFiles = new ArrayList<>();
static List<File> remoteFiles = new ArrayList<>();
static Socket socket;
ObjectOutputStream output;

public CloudCore(Socket socket) throws Exception{
    this.socket = socket;
    output = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
    output.writeObject("get");
    output.flush();
    ObjectInputStream input = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
    Object obj = input.readObject();
    localFiles = (List<File>)obj;
}
public void putFile(File file){
    if (!localFiles.contains(file))
        localFiles.add(file);
        FileCommand fileCommand = new FileCommand(file,"add");
    try(ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream())) {
        out.writeObject((Object)fileCommand);
        out.flush();
    } catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println("bitch");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
```

Сервер:

```
public class NetworkCore {
List<File> files = new ArrayList<File>();
InputStream inputStream;
OutputStream outputStream;
public NetworkCore() throws Exception{
    ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(9999);
    while (true){
        Socket socket = server.accept();
        inputStream = socket.getInputStream();
        outputStream = socket.getOutputStream();
        if (socket.isConnected()) System.out.println("Good, client is connected!");
        ObjectInputStream inStream = new ObjectInputStream(inputStream);
        ObjectOutputStream outStream = new ObjectOutputStream(outputStream);
        Object obj = inStream.readObject();
        if (obj instanceof String){
            if (obj.toString().equals("get")){
                outStream.writeObject(files);
                outStream.flush();
                outStream.close();
                inStream.close();
            }
        }
        if (obj instanceof FileCommand){
            FileCommand fileCommand = (FileCommand)obj;
            if (fileCommand.getCommand().equals("add"))
                files.add(fileCommand.getFile());
            if (fileCommand.getCommand().equals("del"))
                files.remove(fileCommand.getFile());
            System.out.println(fileCommand.getFile().getName());
            outStream.close();
            inStream.close();
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: попробуйте вместо создания нового `ObjectOutputStream` в `putFile` использовать тот, что вы создали в конструкторе.

Answer (score 2):

Ответ оказался весьма прост: следовало использовать ObjectOutputStream, созданный в конструкторе и убрать его за пределы цикла while.